# Sort PHP Array With Two Values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, alphabetical-sort

For example, say I have a PHP array in this format:

```
[
{"optionname":"Math","optionid":"35741"},
{"optionname":"Robotics","optionid":"80229"},
{"optionname":"fndbwoiaghoe","optionid":"1105065296"},
{"optionname":"iphewajgiewohfoidsahg","optionid":"1385274203"},
{"optionname":"wpeogagpoar","optionid":"1030886790"},   
{"optionname":"genpwaighipwe","optionid":"1193090269"}
]
```

How can I sort the array by the value of "optionname" alphabetically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming, due to your code example, that you have a JSON-encoded array.

You want to sort not on the value but on a specific property of the value. PHP can't know which specific property you want to take into account. You have to give PHP a way to know which object comes in front of another with your own function. Then you can tell PHP to use that function for the sorting comparison using [`usort()`](http://be1.php.net/usort).

```
$arr = json_decode('
[
    {"optionname":"Math","optionid":"35741"},
    {"optionname":"Robotics","optionid":"80229"},
    {"optionname":"fndbwoiaghoe","optionid":"1105065296"},
    {"optionname":"iphewajgiewohfoidsahg","optionid":"1385274203"},
    {"optionname":"wpeogagpoar","optionid":"1030886790"},   
    {"optionname":"genpwaighipwe","optionid":"1193090269"}
]
');

usort($arr, function ($obj1, $obj2) {
    return strcasecmp($obj1->optionname, $obj2->optionname);
});

$arr = json_encode($arr);
```

Note that the code above compares the optionname property case insensitive. If you want PHP to take case into account, replace `strcasecmp` with `strcmp`.

Edit: If you are using a PHP version older than 5.3, anonymous functions (like the one used as the second parameter to the `usort()` function above) are not yet supported. The version below should work then.

```
$arr = json_decode('
[
    {"optionname":"Math","optionid":"35741"},
    {"optionname":"Robotics","optionid":"80229"},
    {"optionname":"fndbwoiaghoe","optionid":"1105065296"},
    {"optionname":"iphewajgiewohfoidsahg","optionid":"1385274203"},
    {"optionname":"wpeogagpoar","optionid":"1030886790"},   
    {"optionname":"genpwaighipwe","optionid":"1193090269"}
]
');

function compareObjects($obj1, $obj2)
{
    return strcasecmp($obj1->optionname, $obj2->optionname);
}
usort($arr, 'compareObjects');

$arr = json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: is it supposed to be $obj2->optionid? or optionname

Comment: Your question is "How can I sort the array by the value of "optionname" alphabetically?". Then the sorting function needs to compare the `optionname` of the two given objects to compare. Did you want to compare on both `optionname` AND `optionid`, like @dev-null-dweller suggested?

Comment: im getting an "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION" on the first line, usort(...)

Comment: The function just compares the "optionname" field of both objects (records), and returns a value that `sort` can use to order the array items. Thus: `$obj1->optionname` vs. `$obj2->optionname`

Comment: The syntax I use in my solution is only supported in PHP 5.3 and above. Are you using an older PHP version? If so, write the comparison function separate (`function compareOptions($obj1, $obj2) {...}`) and pass it by name (`usort($arr, 'compareOptions');`).

Comment: function compareOptions($obj1, $obj2) {
 return strcasecmp($obj1->optionname, $obj2->optionname);
}
usort($searchoptions, compareOptions());

this isn't working either, im sorry, im new to php, if you don't mind can you write it out fully

Comment: You need to pass the function name to usort as a string: `usort($searchoptions, 'compareOptions');`. I'll update my answer to have a solution for PHP versions < 5.3.

Comment: ok fixed all my errors, but the array is 
[{"optionname":"wpeogagpoar","optionid":"1030886790"},{"optionname":"genpwaighipwe","optionid":"1193090269"},{"optionname":"iphewajgiewohfoidsahg","optionid":"1385274203"},{"optionname":"fndbwoiaghoe","optionid":"1105065296"},{"optionname":"Robotics","optionid":"80229"},{"optionname":"InventSBHS","optionid":"35741"}]

i cannot get it into alphabetical order

Comment: Could you please clarify the problems you are still having in your original question? Thanks.

Comment: I want the array to be sorted alphabetically based on all the optionnames, it appears that the array changed but it is still not alphabetical

Comment: It is working when I test it. You can see for yourself here: http://codepad.org/uuEw2uqP or by copying the example in my answer here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ .

Comment: wtf why isn't it working for me: http://clubbedin.zymichost.com/search.php

this is my server

Comment: i have the same exact code as you had

Comment: I have no way to answer that.